# Git clone ask me to commit files

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am new using Git.

Yesterday I did a Clone, and after playing around (did lots of merging/branching) I decided to start brand new.

So I deleted repositories, deleted all files including the main folder.

I re-created the folder, then did Clone.

Problem is as soon as Clone finishes, I suddenly has list of files I need to commit.

Any idea why it happens and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both jsexpert and forvaidya answers - however both returned error saying "Not a valid git repository".

I think I got this error because I have deleted the Repository (and the folder/files) again.

Although I am not sure what happens still, when I tried to Clone using Visual Studio it fixes the problems.

Initially I did Clone via Atlassians Source Tree.

Comment: OK In that case you (might) have removed ~/.git folder. However you can try those steps on a trial clone in your ~. and let all know the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is called as dirty repository state. 
Please stash those files using command "git stash save :something"

git reset --hard origin/master (brings you back to original state)

Later create a topic branch an apply this stash.

Answer (score 1):

Clean your working directory for tracked/untracked files:

```
git clean -xfd
git clean -Xfd
git reset HEAD --hard
```

clean is executed twice. once with capital x and the other one wisth lower x.